# What happened to ML.Net MatrixFactorizationTrainer Class after ML.Net 0.17.0 version?

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

I am new at machine learning and following the `microsoft ml.net` documentation so I create an .net core console app and following the instructions but I got stuck at creating an instance of `MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options`.

when I looked it up I learned that `MatrixFactorizationTrainer` class was in `ML.Net 0.17.0 version` not in my version which is `1.4.0` so
is it removed  or ıs it moved to some other namespace or is it replaced by something else ?

if it is, by which class? Can anyone enlighten me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was broken out into its own NuGet as [Microsoft.ML.Recommender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.Recommender/).

That should have all that you need to keep going. :)